# Secret copy to clipboard JavaScript function in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, copy, clipboard

**Update**

Looks like [browsers are starting to support copy natively in JS](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en)

---

In the console windows of both Chrome and Firefox on Mac I can execute

```
copy("party in your clipboard!");
```

and the text gets copied to my clipboard. I have searched SO and Google and can't seem to find anything on this.

- Are these specific to each browser?
- Where can I find more information on
  these JavaScript functions?

Browser versions:

[image]
[image]

JavaScript returned from Chrome console when executing 'copy'

```
function (object)
    {
        if (injectedScript._type(object) === "node") {
            var nodeId = InjectedScriptHost.pushNodePathToFrontend(object, false, false);
            InjectedScriptHost.copyNode(nodeId);
        } else
            InjectedScriptHost.copyText(object);
    }
```

- What does this code mean?

Here are 2 screenshots of executing copy function in Chrome console with all chrome extensions disabled

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Firefox console are you using, Error Console?

Comment: I'm no C++ programmer, but I found `void InjectedScriptHost::copyText(const String& text)` in http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7533.18.1/inspector/InjectedScriptHost.cpp

Comment: @Kai, Hmmmmmm... looks like maybe it is built in to Apple's open source webkit then?

Comment: Unfortunately this command doesn't work from a Chrome extension, so it must be specific to the developer tools console in WebKit.

Comment: confirm this also works with Safari. Nice find!

Comment: It looks like this works without Firebug as well. :D
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I believe these are predefined Firebug console functions - at least that seems to be the case for Firebug. If you try calling `window.copy` for instance, you'll get a warning about function not defined, so it's definitely not a browser function, and cannot be used in normal JavaScript files. The following functions also seems to work in the JavaScript console, after playing around with it a bit:

- `clear()`
- `profile()`

---

Running these in the Chrome console reveals the source behind these functions in the Webkit console:

```
> profile
function ()
{
return console.profile.apply(console, arguments)
}

> clear
function ()
{
InjectedScriptHost.clearConsoleMessages();
}

> copy
function (object)
{
if (injectedScript._type(object) === "node")
object = object.outerHTML;
InjectedScriptHost.copyText(object);
}
```

While the [Firebug source](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.7/content/firebug/commandLine.js?r=8810#1169) also defines a list of functions:

```
this.clear = function()  // no web page interaction
{
    Firebug.Console.clear(context);
};

this.inspect = function(obj, panelName)  // no web page interaction
{
    Firebug.chrome.select(obj, panelName);
};

this.keys = function(o)
{
    return FBL.keys(o);  // the object is from the page, unwrapped
};

this.values = function(o)
{
    return FBL.values(o); // the object is from the page, unwrapped
};

// etc...
```

Comment: Seems that this doesn't work in Chrome 44 when using node-inspector debugging console. `Clipboard is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using chrome://inspect`

Comment: Nice. This works in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)!

Comment: On my Chrome developer tool looks like it's working and also works `window.copy('content')` (on Firefox only with `copy('content')` works)

Comment: I'm on the new Edge and copy works as well.

Answer (score 4):

## Modern response

Nowadays you can use the new API that works cross browsers, you can add an input text hidden on the DOM, select it and then run `document.execCommand('copy');`

Reference:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/cut-and-copy-commands/

## Ancient response times

Here you can see the reference copy command of Chrome Dev tools:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#copy

You shouldn't use this commands on real JS cross-browsers (just for debugging on the console so-to-speak).