# How do I execute data in Webkit consoles by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, webkit, console, copy-paste

I need to use the `copy()` function for my website, which I found can be used in the console of Webkit browsers but not in the markup of my page. So what I wanted to ask is, how do I write some javascript code which triggers execution of code in Webkit consoles?

Thanks,

Lucas

N.B. Please comment on any misunderstandings or vague points in my question. I will strive to improve.

P.S. I got this `copy()` idea from here: [Secret copy to clipboard Javascript function in Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559180/secret-copy-to-clipboard-javascript-function-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the clipboard from javascript due to security reasons. You could use flash though. See the answer to this question:

[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)