# Why is Apple loading an anonymous script into my web application?

Tags: javascript

I found this while browsing my site, using the developer tools.  What is it for?  Is this part of Safari, if so why isn't it part of the nitro engine.

It only shows as an anonymous script.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 Apple Inc.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1.  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2.  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3.  Neither the name of Apple Computer, Inc. ("Apple") nor the names of
 *     its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY APPLE AND ITS CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE OR ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF
 * THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

(function (InjectedScriptHost, inspectedWindow, injectedScriptId) {

function bind(thisObject, memberFunction)
{
    var func = memberFunction;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    function bound()
    {
        return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
    }
    bound.toString = function() {
        return "bound: " + func;
    };
    return bound;
}

var InjectedScript = function()
{
    this._lastBoundObjectId = 1;
    this._idToWrappedObject = {};
    this._idToObjectGroupName = {};
    this._objectGroups = {};
}

InjectedScript.primitiveTypes = {
    undefined: true,
    boolean: true,
    number: true,
    string: true
}

InjectedScript.prototype = {
    isPrimitiveValue: function(object)
    {
        // FIXME(33716): typeof document.all is always 'undefined'.
        return InjectedScript.primitiveTypes[typeof object] && !this._isHTMLAllCollection(object);
    },

    wrapObject: function(object, groupName, canAccessInspectedWindow)
    {
        if (canAccessInspectedWindow)
            return this._wrapObject(object, groupName);

        var result = {};
        result.type = typeof object;
        if (this._isPrimitiveValue(object))
            result.value = object;
        else
            result.description = this._toString(object);
        return result;
    },

    inspectNode: function(object)
    {
        this._inspect(object);
    },

    _inspect: function(object)
    {
        if (arguments.length === 0)
            return;

        var objectId = this._wrapObject(object, "");
        var hints = {};

        switch (injectedScript._describe(object)) {
            case "Database":
                var databaseId = InjectedScriptHost.databaseId(object)
                if (databaseId)
                    hints.databaseId = databaseId;
                break;
            case "Storage":
                var storageId = InjectedScriptHost.storageId(object)
                if (storageId)
                    hints.domStorageId = storageId;
                break;
        }
        InjectedScriptHost.inspect(objectId, hints);
        return object;
    },

    // This method cannot throw.
    _wrapObject: function(object, objectGroupName, forceValueType)
    {
        try {
            return new InjectedScript.RemoteObject(object, objectGroupName, forceValueType);
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                var description = injectedScript._describe(e);
            } catch (ex) {
                var description = "<failed to convert exception to string>";
            }
            return new InjectedScript.RemoteObject(description);
        }
    },

    _bind: function(object, objectGroupName)
    {
        var id = this._lastBoundObjectId++;
        this._idToWrappedObject[id] = object;
        var objectId = "{\"injectedScriptId\":" + injectedScriptId + ",\"id\":" + id + "}";
        if (objectGroupName) {
            var group = this._objectGroups[objectGroupName];
            if (!group) {
                group = [];
                this._objectGroups[objectGroupName] = group;
            }
            group.push(id);
            this._idToObjectGroupName[id] = objectGroupName;
        }
        return objectId;
    },

    _parseObjectId: function(objectId)
    {
        return eval("(" + objectId + ")");
    },

    releaseObjectGroup: function(objectGroupName)
    {
        var group = this._objectGroups[objectGroupName];
        if (!group)
            return;
        for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++)
            this._releaseObject(group[i]);
        delete this._objectGroups[objectGroupName];
    },

    dispatch: function(methodName, args)
    {
        var argsArray = eval("(" + args + ")");
        var result = this[methodName].apply(this, argsArray);
        if (typeof result === "undefined") {
            inspectedWindow.console.error("Web Inspector error: InjectedScript.%s returns undefined", methodName);
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    },

    getProperties: function(objectId, ownProperties)
    {
        var parsedObjectId = this._parseObjectId(objectId);
        var object = this._objectForId(parsedObjectId);
        var objectGroupName = this._idToObjectGroupName[parsedObjectId.id];

        if (!this._isDefined(object))
            return false;
        var descriptors = this._propertyDescriptors(object, ownProperties);

        // Go over properties, wrap object values.
        if (descriptors.length === 0 && "arguments" in object) {
            // Fill in JSC scope object.
            for (var key in object)
                descriptors.push({ name: key, value: object[key], writable: false, configurable: false, enumerable: true});
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < descriptors.length; ++i) {
            var descriptor = descriptors[i];
            if ("get" in descriptor)
                descriptor.get = this._wrapObject(descriptor.get, objectGroupName);
            if ("set" in descriptor)
                descriptor.set = this._wrapObject(descriptor.set, objectGroupName);
            if ("value" in descriptor)
                descriptor.value = this._wrapObject(descriptor.value, objectGroupName);
            if (!("configurable" in descriptor))
                descriptor.configurable = false;
            if (!("enumerable" in descriptor))
                descriptor.enumerable = false;

        }
        return descriptors;
    },

    getFunctionDetails: function(functionId)
    {
        var parsedFunctionId = this._parseObjectId(functionId);
        var func = this._objectForId(parsedFunctionId);
        if (typeof func !== "function")
            return "Cannot resolve function by id.";
        return InjectedScriptHost.functionDetails(func);
    },

    releaseObject: function(objectId)
    {
        var parsedObjectId = this._parseObjectId(objectId);
        this._releaseObject(parsedObjectId.id);
    },

    _releaseObject: function(id)
    {
        delete this._idToWrappedObject[id];
        delete this._idToObjectGroupName[id];
    },

    _propertyDescriptors: function(object, ownProperties)
    {
        var descriptors = [];
        var nameProcessed = {};
        nameProcessed.__proto__ = null;
        for (var o = object; this._isDefined(o); o = o.__proto__) {
            var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o);
            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
                var name = names[i];
                if (nameProcessed[name])
                    continue;

                try {
                    nameProcessed[name] = true;
                    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, name);
                    if (!descriptor) {
                        // Not all bindings provide proper descriptors. Fall back to the writable, configurable property.
                        try {
                            descriptors.push({ name: name, value: object[name], writable: false, configurable: false, enumerable: false});
                        } catch (e) {
                            // Silent catch.
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    var descriptor = {};
                    descriptor.value = e;
                    descriptor.wasThrown = true;
                }

                descriptor.name = name;
                descriptors.push(descriptor); 
            }
            if (ownProperties) {
                if (object.__proto__)
                    descriptors.push({ name: "__proto__", value: object.__proto__, writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: false});
                break;
            }
        }
        return descriptors;
    },

    evaluate: function(expression, objectGroup, injectCommandLineAPI, returnByValue)
    {
        return this._evaluateAndWrap(inspectedWindow.eval, inspectedWindow, expression, objectGroup, false, injectCommandLineAPI, returnByValue);
    },

    callFunctionOn: function(objectId, expression, args, returnByValue)
    {
        var parsedObjectId = this._parseObjectId(objectId);
        var object = this._objectForId(parsedObjectId);
        if (!object)
            return "Could not find object with given id";

        if (args) {
            var resolvedArgs = [];
            args = eval(args);
            for (var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                var objectId = args[i].objectId;
                if (objectId) {
                    var parsedArgId = this._parseObjectId(objectId);
                    if (!parsedArgId || parsedArgId.injectedScriptId !== injectedScriptId)
                        return "Arguments should belong to the same JavaScript world as the target object.";

                    var resolvedArg = this._objectForId(parsedArgId);
                    if (!resolvedArg)
                        return "Could not find object with given id";

                    resolvedArgs.push(resolvedArg);
                } else if ("value" in args[i])
                    resolvedArgs.push(args[i].value);
                else
                    resolvedArgs.push(undefined);
            }
        }

        try {
            var objectGroup = this._idToObjectGroupName[parsedObjectId.id];
            var func = eval("(" + expression + ")");
            if (typeof func !== "function")
                return "Given expression does not evaluate to a function";

            return { wasThrown: false,
                     result: this._wrapObject(func.apply(object, resolvedArgs), objectGroup, returnByValue) };
        } catch (e) {
            return this._createThrownValue(e, objectGroup);
        }
    },

    _evaluateAndWrap: function(evalFunction, object, expression, objectGroup, isEvalOnCallFrame, injectCommandLineAPI, returnByValue)
    {
        try {
            return { wasThrown: false,
                     result: this._wrapObject(this._evaluateOn(evalFunction, object, expression, isEvalOnCallFrame, injectCommandLineAPI), objectGroup, returnByValue) };
        } catch (e) {
            return this._createThrownValue(e, objectGroup);
        }
    },

    _createThrownValue: function(value, objectGroup)
    {
        var remoteObject = this._wrapObject(value, objectGroup);
        try {
            remoteObject.description = this._toString(value);
        } catch (e) {}
        return { wasThrown: true,
                 result: remoteObject };
    },

    _evaluateOn: function(evalFunction, object, expression, isEvalOnCallFrame, injectCommandLineAPI)
    {
        // Only install command line api object for the time of evaluation.
        // Surround the expression in with statements to inject our command line API so that
        // the window object properties still take more precedent than our API functions.

        try {
            if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console) {
                inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI = new CommandLineAPI(this._commandLineAPIImpl, isEvalOnCallFrame ? object : null);
                expression = "with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {\n" + expression + "\n}";
            }
            return evalFunction.call(object, expression);
        } finally {
            if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console)
                delete inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI;
        }
    },

    wrapCallFrames: function(callFrame)
    {
        if (!callFrame)
            return false;

        var result = [];
        var depth = 0;
        do {
            result.push(new InjectedScript.CallFrameProxy(depth++, callFrame));
            callFrame = callFrame.caller;
        } while (callFrame);
        return result;
    },

    evaluateOnCallFrame: function(topCallFrame, callFrameId, expression, objectGroup, injectCommandLineAPI, returnByValue)
    {
        var callFrame = this._callFrameForId(topCallFrame, callFrameId);
        if (!callFrame)
            return "Could not find call frame with given id";
        return this._evaluateAndWrap(callFrame.evaluate, callFrame, expression, objectGroup, true, injectCommandLineAPI, returnByValue);
    },

    _callFrameForId: function(topCallFrame, callFrameId)
    {
        var parsedCallFrameId = eval("(" + callFrameId + ")");
        var ordinal = parsedCallFrameId.ordinal;
        var callFrame = topCallFrame;
        while (--ordinal >= 0 && callFrame)
            callFrame = callFrame.caller;
        return callFrame;
    },

    _objectForId: function(objectId)
    {
        return this._idToWrappedObject[objectId.id];
    },

    nodeForObjectId: function(objectId)
    {
        var parsedObjectId = this._parseObjectId(objectId);
        var object = this._objectForId(parsedObjectId);
        if (!object || this._subtype(object) !== "node")
            return null;
        return object;
    },

    _isDefined: function(object)
    {
        return object || this._isHTMLAllCollection(object);
    },

    _isHTMLAllCollection: function(object)
    {
        // document.all is reported as undefined, but we still want to process it.
        return (typeof object === "undefined") && InjectedScriptHost.isHTMLAllCollection(object);
    },

    _subtype: function(obj)
    {
        if (obj === null)
            return "null";

        var type = typeof obj;
        if (this.isPrimitiveValue(obj))
            return null;

        if (this._isHTMLAllCollection(obj))
            return "array";

        var preciseType = InjectedScriptHost.type(obj);
        if (preciseType)
            return preciseType;

        // FireBug's array detection.
        try {
            if (typeof obj.splice === "function" && isFinite(obj.length))
                return "array";
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Arguments]" && isFinite(obj.length)) // arguments.
                return "array";
        } catch (e) {
        }

        // If owning frame has navigated to somewhere else window properties will be undefined.
        return null;
    },

    _describe: function(obj)
    {
        if (this.isPrimitiveValue(obj))
            return null;

        // Type is object, get subtype.
        var subtype = this._subtype(obj);

        if (subtype === "regexp")
            return this._toString(obj);

        if (subtype === "date")
            return this._toString(obj);

        var className = InjectedScriptHost.internalConstructorName(obj);
        if (subtype === "array") {
            if (typeof obj.length === "number")
                className += "[" + obj.length + "]";
            return className;
        }

        // NodeList in JSC is a function, check for array prior to this.
        if (typeof obj === "function")
            return this._toString(obj);

        if (className === "Object") {
            // In Chromium DOM wrapper prototypes will have Object as their constructor name,
            // get the real DOM wrapper name from the constructor property.
            var constructorName = obj.constructor && obj.constructor.name;
            if (constructorName)
                return constructorName;
        }
        return className;
    },

    _toString: function(obj)
    {
        // We don't use String(obj) because inspectedWindow.String is undefined if owning frame navigated to another page.
        return "" + obj;
    }
}

var injectedScript = new InjectedScript();

InjectedScript.RemoteObject = function(object, objectGroupName, forceValueType)
{
    this.type = typeof object;
    if (injectedScript.isPrimitiveValue(object) || object === null || forceValueType) {
        // We don't send undefined values over JSON.
        if (typeof object !== "undefined")
            this.value = object;

        // Null object is object with 'null' subtype'
        if (object === null)
            this.subtype = "null";

        // Provide user-friendly number values.
        if (typeof object === "number")
            this.description = object + "";
        return;
    }

    this.objectId = injectedScript._bind(object, objectGroupName);
    var subtype = injectedScript._subtype(object)
    if (subtype)
        this.subtype = subtype;
    this.className = InjectedScriptHost.internalConstructorName(object);
    this.description = injectedScript._describe(object);
}

InjectedScript.CallFrameProxy = function(ordinal, callFrame)
{
    this.callFrameId = "{\"ordinal\":" + ordinal + ",\"injectedScriptId\":" + injectedScriptId + "}";
    this.functionName = (callFrame.type === "function" ? callFrame.functionName : "");
    this.location = { scriptId: String(callFrame.sourceID), lineNumber: callFrame.line, columnNumber: callFrame.column };
    this.scopeChain = this._wrapScopeChain(callFrame);
    this.this = injectedScript._wrapObject(callFrame.thisObject, "backtrace");
}

InjectedScript.CallFrameProxy.prototype = {
    _wrapScopeChain: function(callFrame)
    {
        const GLOBAL_SCOPE = 0;
        const LOCAL_SCOPE = 1;
        const WITH_SCOPE = 2;
        const CLOSURE_SCOPE = 3;
        const CATCH_SCOPE = 4;

        var scopeTypeNames = {};
        scopeTypeNames[GLOBAL_SCOPE] = "global";
        scopeTypeNames[LOCAL_SCOPE] = "local";
        scopeTypeNames[WITH_SCOPE] = "with";
        scopeTypeNames[CLOSURE_SCOPE] = "closure";
        scopeTypeNames[CATCH_SCOPE] = "catch";

        var scopeChain = callFrame.scopeChain;
        var scopeChainProxy = [];
        var foundLocalScope = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < scopeChain.length; i++) {
            var scope = {};
            scope.object = injectedScript._wrapObject(scopeChain[i], "backtrace");

            var scopeType = callFrame.scopeType(i);
            scope.type = scopeTypeNames[scopeType];
            scopeChainProxy.push(scope);
        }
        return scopeChainProxy;
    }
}

function CommandLineAPI(commandLineAPIImpl, callFrame)
{
    function inScopeVariables(member)
    {
        if (!callFrame)
            return false;

        var scopeChain = callFrame.scopeChain;
        for (var i = 0; i < scopeChain.length; ++i) {
            if (member in scopeChain[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < CommandLineAPI.members_.length; ++i) {
        var member = CommandLineAPI.members_[i];
        if (member in inspectedWindow || inScopeVariables(member))
            continue;

        this[member] = bind(commandLineAPIImpl, commandLineAPIImpl[member]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        var member = "$" + i;
        if (member in inspectedWindow || inScopeVariables(member))
            continue;

        this.__defineGetter__("$" + i, bind(commandLineAPIImpl, commandLineAPIImpl._inspectedObject, i));
    }
}

CommandLineAPI.members_ = [
    "$", "$$", "$x", "dir", "dirxml", "keys", "values", "profile", "profileEnd",
    "monitorEvents", "unmonitorEvents", "inspect", "copy", "clear", "getEventListeners"
];

function CommandLineAPIImpl()
{
}

CommandLineAPIImpl.prototype = {
    $: function()
    {
        return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
    },

    $$: function()
    {
        return document.querySelectorAll.apply(document, arguments)
    },

    $x: function(xpath, context)
    {
        var doc = (context && context.ownerDocument) || inspectedWindow.document;
        var result = doc.evaluate(xpath, context || doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        switch (result.resultType) {
        case XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE:
            return result.numberValue;
        case XPathResult.STRING_TYPE:
            return result.stringValue;
        case XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE:
            return result.booleanValue;
        default:
            var nodes = [];
            var node;
            while (node = result.iterateNext())
                nodes.push(node);
            return nodes;
        }
    },

    dir: function()
    {
        return console.dir.apply(console, arguments)
    },

    dirxml: function()
    {
        return console.dirxml.apply(console, arguments)
    },

    keys: function(object)
    {
        return Object.keys(object);
    },

    values: function(object)
    {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in object)
            result.push(object[key]);
        return result;
    },

    profile: function()
    {
        return console.profile.apply(console, arguments)
    },

    profileEnd: function()
    {
        return console.profileEnd.apply(console, arguments)
    },

    monitorEvents: function(object, types)
    {
        if (!object || !object.addEventListener || !object.removeEventListener)
            return;
        types = this._normalizeEventTypes(types);
        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
            object.removeEventListener(types[i], this._logEvent, false);
            object.addEventListener(types[i], this._logEvent, false);
        }
    },

    unmonitorEvents: function(object, types)
    {
        if (!object || !object.addEventListener || !object.removeEventListener)
            return;
        types = this._normalizeEventTypes(types);
        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i)
            object.removeEventListener(types[i], this._logEvent, false);
    },

    inspect: function(object)
    {
        return injectedScript._inspect(object);
    },

    copy: function(object)
    {
        if (injectedScript._subtype(object) === "node")
            object = object.outerHTML;
        InjectedScriptHost.copyText(object);
    },

    clear: function()
    {
        InjectedScriptHost.clearConsoleMessages();
    },

    getEventListeners: function(node)
    {
        return InjectedScriptHost.getEventListeners(node);
    },

    _inspectedObject: function(num)
    {
        return InjectedScriptHost.inspectedObject(num);
    },

    _normalizeEventTypes: function(types)
    {
        if (typeof types === "undefined")
            types = [ "mouse", "key", "touch", "control", "load", "unload", "abort", "error", "select", "change", "submit", "reset", "focus", "blur", "resize", "scroll", "search", "devicemotion", "deviceorientation" ];
        else if (typeof types === "string")
            types = [ types ];

        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            if (types[i] === "mouse")
                result.splice(0, 0, "mousedown", "mouseup", "click", "dblclick", "mousemove", "mouseover", "mouseout", "mousewheel");
            else if (types[i] === "key")
                result.splice(0, 0, "keydown", "keyup", "keypress", "textInput");
            else if (types[i] === "touch")
                result.splice(0, 0, "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend", "touchcancel");
            else if (types[i] === "control")
                result.splice(0, 0, "resize", "scroll", "zoom", "focus", "blur", "select", "change", "submit", "reset");
            else
                result.push(types[i]);
        }
        return result;
    },

    _logEvent: function(event)
    {
        console.log(event.type, event);
    }
}

injectedScript._commandLineAPIImpl = new CommandLineAPIImpl();
return injectedScript;
})
```

Comment: Maybe it is injected code for some kind of addon/extension of Safari.

Comment: Maybe it's for debugging?  Like for the console?

Comment: See [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559180/secret-copy-to-clipboard-javascript-function-in-chrome-and-firefox).

Comment: where can i go on the browser to check for this? extension builder?

Comment: At the end, there's `new CommandLineAPIImpl`.  Which makes me think this is from the [Command Line API](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api), which is used (only) in Chrome's (and Safari's, I assume) console.  My guess is that this is injected to "enable" the debugging tools on your webpage.

Comment: Funny, I can't find it any more, it was under the resource icon in the debug console.

Comment: Is there a global I can check for to see if its still there?

Comment: @Rocket - well I have no access to those functions, I'm not sure what caused it to load before and not now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code of unknown origin that went unreachable while discussion was going on (not kidding). 'too localized'

Comment: @stack_temp: I guess you can find it when firing up devtools while devtools are loaded - otherwise it will be hidden from scripts list.

Comment: `why isn't it part of the nitro engine?`. Not everything in a web browser is implemented in C. Mozilla was the first to implement a very minimal C "core" with everything else implemented in javascript (seriously, Firefox is almost 90% javascript running on the XULRunner framework). Other browsers have started to do the same thing with varying degrees of C-to-js mix.

Comment: repeatability can be challenging, oh well just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used by the **web inspector** of WebKit. You can check the source [here](https://webkit.googlesource.com/WebKit/+/master/Source/WebCore/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on zsong's answer, checking the `expression` argument to the `evaluate()` function can help you figure out what script Chrome is trying to run.

For more details, see [Chrome Development Tool: [VM] file from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript).