# Why does chrome's developer console copy-to-clipboard function return the object's toString value sometimes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-console

It's know that `copy` is a special function available inside the developer console of Chrome and Firefox (and potentially other browsers) to copy an object to the clipboard.
<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#copyobject)</sup><sup>[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559180/secret-copy-to-clipboard-javascript-function-in-chrome-and-firefox)</sup>

So why is it that when I copy some highly complex object in chrome to debug in my text editor, parts of it revert to calling its `toString` function, resulting in "[Object object]" when none is specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when the object contains a [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming). For example:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = foo;
copy(foo);
```

Chrome (v54) substituting the object with its string value. In Firefox (v47), if the object has a circular references, the error `/* TypeError: cyclic object value */` to be copied to the clipboard instead.