# export console.log to local file using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, file, loops, console, export

I have a script. I have exported to console.log the elevations by including in for loop.
Now I need to export this console.log to a file (could be text/csv/excel).

```
for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
console.log(elevations[i].elevation);}
```

Could you please help?
Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to export it to a text file from Javascript? Because you can export a console log to a text file from the browser.

But if you want to do it in Javascript, this should work:

```js
let blob = new Blob(["test"]);
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let file = document.createElement(`a`);
file.download = `file.txt`;
file.href = url;
document.body.appendChild(file);
file.click();
file.remove();
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Replace `"test"` with what you want to be in the text file. You can concatenate all elevations in a variable and replace `"test"` with `variable`.

So, for example, you could do:

```
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
    data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
    console.log(elevations[i].elevation);
    text += elevations[i].elevation + "\n";
}
```

And then use `text` in `let blob = new Blob([text]);`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please modify it in order to use it in my example with console.log? All the best.

Comment: @amplatfus You can just concatenate the elevations with a newline (assuming you want each one to be in a separate line). Added an example.

Comment: Thanks @revilheart. I did but when adding let data = new Blob([text]); I got: SyntaxError: redeclaration of var data. After delete I do not have this error. Question 1: please do you know why? Question 2: in what location will be the file saved? All the best!

Comment: @amplatfus Ah, it's because you're already using a variable named `data`, just change the name of the variable to something else. The file will be saved to your computer (you should get a window asking you where, just as if you were downloading a regular file). Edited the answer to use `blob` instead of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

In google chrome console you can try the function copy():

copy(elevations)

This function copy elevations value in your clipboard. Hope it's help.

Comment: Thank you. i tried but I dot below error:ReferenceError: copy is not defined [Learn More]

Comment: For info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559180/secret-copy-to-clipboard-javascript-function-in-chrome-and-firefox